# Are push in connectors up to code?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance

Just came across a neat product at the local hardware store, but I wonder if they are up to code and safe to use.  They are a wire nut that allows you to simply push the wires in, instead of twisting on a traditional wire nut.

They cost slightly more, and you have to keep a wider variety of connectors on hand since they vary by the number of wires that can be connected.

they accept 12-22 AWG solid and 12-22 AWG stranded wire, and are rated at 600 VAC.  They come in a variety of sizes from 2 - 8 'ports', so they should be up to any job.

Has anybody ever used these, and are they code compliant in the United States?  Is there any danger of the wires slipping out over time?

[image: 2-port connector]
[image: 3-port connector]
[image: 4-port connector]
[image: 5-port connector]
[image: 6-port connector]
[image: 8-port connector]

[electricalbasics.com](http://www.electricalbasics.com/acatalog/Push_In_Wire_Connectors.html#EBWC-19-PI2-YW)

Found some standards information:
(Ideal Industries IN-SURE(TM) PUSH-IN CONNECTORS)

> UL 486C, UL 467 GROUNDING
>  CSA
>   C22.2 #188
>  IEC 998-2-2
>  CE
>   CERTIFIED
>  RoHS COMPLIANT
>  UL
>   94V-2 FLAME RATING
>  US PATENT
>   7,507,106
>  US & FOREIGN PATENTS
>   PENDING

## UPDATE:

I finally got my hands on some of these things, and I'll tell you what. If you can pull the wires out through normal means once they're locked in, you deserve some type of prize.  I did find a way to pull the wires out, but I doubt they'll ever see enough movement while in use to allow the wires to slip out.  If you spin the wires back and forth while you pull, they will eventually work their way out (this is the official way to remove wires [according to an IDEAL spokesperson](http://diy.blogoverflow.com/2012/01/tool-review-ideal-in-sure-push-in-wire-connectors/#comment-71253)).  Doing this chews the wire up pretty bad, leaving a bunch of nicks along the length of the wire.

They say not to reuse them, and I can see why. Removing the wire can leave fairly deep gouges in the wire. If you ever have to remove them, you'll likely have to trim the wire back and restrip it. However, Even after torturing them (including taking them apart), they still held the wire when it was reinserted.

So as long as your wiring is not subjected to constant twisting and pulling, you should have no problems with wires pulling out of these things.

## UPDATE:

I think I finally found the relevant section in the code that would apply to these devices.

> ## National Electrical Code 2014
>
> ### Article 110 - Requirements for Electrical Installations
>
> #### I. General
>
> **110.14 Electrical Connections.**
>
> **(B) Splices.** `Conductors shall be spliced or joined with splicing devices identiﬁed for the use` or by brazing, welding,
>   or soldering with a fusible metal or alloy. Soldered splices shall
>   ﬁrst be spliced or joined so as to be mechanically and electrically
>   secure without solder and then be soldered. `All splices and joints
>   and the free ends of conductors shall be covered with an insulation
>   equivalent to that of the conductors or with an identified insulating device.`
>
> Wire connectors or splicing means
>   installed on conductors for direct burial shall be listed for such
>   use.

I would say these devices fit both criteria. They are identified for the use, and they provide insulation equivalent to the conductors.

Comment: You might want to mention where you are, as codes vary by locality. Did you ask at the store? They are likely to know where these products are legit to use.

Comment: I would have thought that the store wouldn't stock them if they were illegal. I suppose they could have multiple uses.

Comment: "you have to keep a wider variety of connectors on hand" - just keep a bunch of 4-port connectors around; daisy-chain chain them if you ever need more.

Comment: @ChrisF: it's not illegal to sell many products that would not meet minimum code for certain applications. For example, big box stores still sell non-tamper-resistant receptacles, but they've been required for residential applications for several years now by NEC 2008 (the minimum code in many places here in the US).

Comment: The April issue of The Family Handyman magazine just had a little blurb about these. Unfortunately, it didn't say anything about code approval either. I think the first comment above, about how local codes vary, is the key point.

Comment: I'd be interested to see how well they work.  The old-fashioned wire nuts seem to fall off with frightening regularity.  I suspect the only reason they're code is because nothing better has come out yet.  Hopefully this is the something better.

Comment: Wondering if they are rated and safe to use to join aluminum wire to copper wire.

Comment: @Feriheit - From what I've read they are only good for same wire type connections, but can be used with different metals e.g. copper -> copper, aluminium -> aluminium. Not sure if they make different connectors for aluminium and copper, or if the same connectors can be used with either.

Comment: I really like these for ground wires (especially in metal boxes), where I need to join many, many wires together. If you think you might need to add more in the future, leave 1 slot open; use it to daisychain to the next one.

Comment: One thing might be to look at the connectors that are used to join the electrical connections between the two halves of a double wide or modular home.

Comment: I have a work associate who just experienced a failure with these connectors. A wire came loose, disabling a GFI circuit. Electrician indicated a wire had come loose from the connector. This occurred in a box.

Comment: I can't speak to the question of whether they're legal per the NEC, but I'm skeptical that they'll carry as much current through that spring-loaded connection as the wire that fits the connection can carry... and as such, I don't imagine that I'll ever use them. If they CANNOT carry the full current load, then they introduce a weak link.

Comment: @TDHofstetter They are UL tested and labeled at the same (or greater) current as the wire they are listed for.

Comment: Wait - from your initial description it sounded like they were a "one size fits all" thing that would work with wires of gauge 12 to 22. Are they actually gauge-specific? I'd like to get hold of one or two so I could pull it apart & decide for sure if I like it...

Comment: They accept a range of wire sizes, but are rated at or above the maximum current of the largest size conductor they work with.

Comment: @TDHofstetter I ripped some apart and [blogged about it](http://diy.blogoverflow.com/2012/01/tool-review-ideal-in-sure-push-in-wire-connectors/)

Comment: Interesting. I'll need to get some apart myself so I can examine the contacts close-up. I wonder... won't these things give electricians a lot more work later down the line, when they need to alter some existing wiring but have to shorten the wire to get it done? If already short (from installation or from previous maintenance), they'd have no recourse but to pull a new run of wire. Wire nuts VERY seldom require shortening the wire; even if the wire gets heavily twisted, it's still undamaged and can be straightened easily.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I will not speak to the code issue as other already have. But, I did use them when building my new home a few years ago and, for me, they passed inspection.

While the package does say they can be used for stranded wire, I did not find that they worked that easily with stranded wire (I was using some computer controlled switches with pigtails instead of screws). But, they did work. I just had to twist the strands fairly tight first.

As far as coming loose? Not the ones I was using. If memory serves me correctly, I think there is a little hole that you can push the spring up with to release the wire because it is so tight.

Comment: It think the "tightness" may be relative to the brand. The Ideal ones are easily removed from solid wire by simple twisting and pulling simultaneously. It's true that this would likely happen only when you're purposefully removing them, but I thought I'd mention none of the ones I've used had a spring release.

Comment: Yes, that is correct too. Simple, but purposeful twisting and pulling of the wire will release the wire from the connector. And you are also correct that the "extra" hole on the connector is not for a spring release, at least not on the two wire connector.

Answer (score 5):

In the UK they are allowed, see https://www.wagobox.com/

However they must always be in some sort of box and the correct connect must be used.

Answer (score 1):

I know there are some types of butt connectors that are suitable for in-wall splicing of NM wires, but I don't know if the particular types you are looking at would be acceptable. A quick Google search suggests you would need to look at NEC 2002 articles 545, 550, 551 and 334-40B.

Also, look at the answer on this site:

[Is there a way to simply splice in an additional length of 12/2 NM-B cable?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/4493/minimal-effort-code-legal-way-to-splice-in-additional-length-of-120-volt-12-2-nm)

Comment: The connectors I'm looking at are intended to replace traditional wire nuts, and are not to be used outside of a junction box.

Answer (score 1):

I was exited to try these Wago connectors as I don't really like wire nuts.  But the wire rotates in the connector pretty easy: I did not feel comfortable using them.  I feel that any contact that can rotate or move will eventually generate a problem.

Others may feel differently: I won't use them again.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found anything in the 2014 NEC that would make push-in connectors illegal to use as long as the manufacturer's instructions are followed and the ones used are UL listed for the application. But as always the NEC is a minimum standard that gives the AHJ (authority having jurisdiction) the ability to make requirements over and above the guidelines in the NEC.

Answer (score 0):

In my professional experience with push in connectors tbe verdict is always the same... give it 5 to 10 years and the pressure plate holding the wire in loses it strength and lets the wires come loose. Next comes a bad connection at best. My advice would be to throw the butt connectors in the trash and use a wingnut instead

Comment: Did it really happen to you? What brand was it? I'm using wago clamps for a long time and never had a single problem(or even heard about one): http://www.wago.us/products/terminal-blocks-and-connectors/installation-connectors/overview/
My advice is to throw wingnuts in trash and use push-in or lever action connectors.

Comment: wing nuts use pressure as well... have you ever pulled the innards out? based on that logic, the only longish term solution would be soldering....

Answer (score -1):

The instructions for the push in connectors I have seen disallow their use with aluminum wire. This makes sense because push in (stab in connections) have always been against code for aluminum wire.

I have done rework in a house where the make up was done using these type of connectors. It seems to make for a neat installation. I did not see any failures. This house is about 15 years old. I would like to know if anyone has seen problems with feed through loads using them.

Comment: Does not address the code question.  Looks like you're asking a new question which should really be posted on its own.

Comment: Ok it's the first time that I have used this site.

Comment: +1, not for Aluminum wire, which should never be 'stabbed-in'.