# How to remove cables from the Philips ballast for fluorescent lamps?

Tags: electrical, lighting, fluorescent

I have a few HF-Performer III TL5 ballasts to to which I connected cables in past. Now I can't take them out

http://www.lighting.philips.com/main/prof/lighting-electronics/fluorescent/fluorescent-fixed-output-gear/hf-performer-iii-for-pl-l-lamps/913713028366_EU/product

The instruction on the housing says that:

- just rotate and pull, but it does not work when I keep them with my fingers and do so, maybe there is a tool for this?

- this is an ADS / Manual connection, but in Google I can't find anything about this connection

On the pictures you can see a ballast with plugged cables and without cables

I ask for you advice

[image: housing instruction]
[image: with cables 1]
[image: with cables 2]
[image: withput cables 1]
[image: withput cables 2]
[image: withput cables 3]

Comment: Notice that there's three arrows. One is pulling *out*, the other two are "rotating" (back and forth). [What type of connector is this and how do I remove it?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/21820/what-type-of-connector-is-this-and-how-do-i-remove-it) : "7. In order to remove a wire, pull and twist the wire back and forth."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use pin. Put it above cable end and remove both pin and cable at the same time

(On last picture it is below, not above)

[image]
[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have stranded wire in the area for solid wire. Can try a pin and work out. Or cut wire pull out strands. Solid goes into the push in area.And you twist to remove. Stranded goes in push down with push down tool for stranded. I would also add one of those plug in type of disconnects for easy replacement. You dont have to shut down circuit to work on fixtures .