# Is splicing in an LB conduit body allowed by the NEC?

Tags: electrical

I'm adding a circuit, but I need to make a splice. Can I splice in an LB conduit body? Will I still be compliant with the NEC?

[image]

Image: https://iaeimagazine.org/features/conduit-bodies-and-their-use-in-accordance-with-the-nec/

Comment: Does the LB have its inside volume (in cubic inches) marked somewhere on it?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. What's an "LB"? (@ThreePhaseEel seems to know, but others wouldn't.)

Comment: @DanielGriscom -- a "LB" is a style of conduit body that elbows out the back, such as [one of these](https://www.garvinindustries.com/fittings/aluminum-and-malleable-iron-conduit-bodies/aluminum-lb/lb100)

Comment: The point of this site is not only to answer a specific person's question, but to build up a body of information that others can consult. Unreferenced acronyms and obscure terminology harm that goal.

Comment: Added image of "LB" and other "L" conduits, since this question seems revived and the above link in the comment is no longer available.

Comment: Maybe specify an LB is a type of Conduit Body or "Pull Hub" (not intended for splicing)

Comment: Yes, you can. However the LB needs to have its volume clearly marked and you have to do fill calcs to determine the legality.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Absolutely not.  No splicing in a conduit body. They are only to help fish wires.

Now -- there is an utterly useless exception.  If the conduit body is stamped with a number of cubic inches, then you can apply the *[junction box fill rules](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/120258/how-do-you-count-the-number-of-wires-in-a-fill-capacity-of-an-outlet-box)* instead. In any size of conduit that's reasonable for your wires, there aren't *nearly* enough cubic inches in the conduit bodies!

You are better off just swapping the conduit body for a junction box. Play with several sizes of box to see which one will line up without having to cut conduit. Been there done that.