# Can I leave an open port when using push-in connectors?

Tags: electrical, connectors

[This question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/5141/are-push-in-connectors-up-to-code) made me aware that push-in type connectors are available and got me thinking about using them in an upcoming rewiring project.

I have three types of junctions in my rewiring project where I personally would find this type of connector to be a valuable time saver.

1. Join 6 wires together
2. Join 5 wires together
3. Join 4 wires together

*Note: Any junctions where more than 6 wires need to be joined will be joined using terminals and I would still prefer to use wing nuts for junction points where 3 wires or less need to be joined together.*

Do I *have* to buy 6-port connectors, 5-port connectors, and 4-port connectors, or is there a safe, permissible, and legal way to just buy a bunch of 6-port connectors and only use the terminals I need (e.g. some kind of rated "plug" that can be inserted into the wiring ports that are unused).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaving open ports is fine. They make smaller sizes for space considerations. Combination packs are available, though they are more expensive when not bought in bulk.

---

[Ideal](http://s3.supplyhouse.com/product_files/30-1033%20-%20Ideal%20-%20Brochure.pdf)'s Twister® wire connectors(p.3) have specifications for the minimum and maximum numbers of wires. Their In-Sure™ push-in connectors(p.15) are only limited by the number of ports and will accept "[any combination of #12-18 AWG solid and stranded copper wires](http://s3.supplyhouse.com/product_files/30-1033%20-%20Ideal%20-%20Product%20Overview.pdf)".

Comment: Thank you. To confirm, leaving an open port is not a violation of NEC 2014 Article 110.14? In this section, the NEC states: "All splices and joints and the free ends of conductors shall be covered with an insulation equivalent to that of the conductors or with an identified insulating device."? The open port leaves the port's metallic connector exposed (albeit recessed and generally well protected against anything that is not like the end of a wire). Supporting evidence for your answer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @UserUser Somewhere in the original question it is purported that since the manufacturer lists them *approved* for use on 12ga, 600v, Cu, they are "covered with an insulation equivalent to that..."