# Can I leave ports open on push-in type wire connectors?

Tags: electrical, wire

I will eventually have 7 ground wires, and then another 7 neutral wires to connect each. (obviously I'm not connecting ground wire to neutral wires). I plan on installing leviton smart light switches.  I found a black colored push-in connector that has 8 ports at home depot. Is it ok to leave 1 port unused? I can buy one for the ground and 1 for the neutral wires I was thinking.

Comment: Don't use push-ins, they are not reliable.

Comment: Yes and yes. Harper's opinion is noted but the push-in connectors you are talking about should be listed for the use by UL and possible the CSA and marked as such on the box. This means they have been tested by a listing laboratory as is required by the National Electrical Code. They have satisfied all requirements to be used for the purpose you  indicated in your question.

Comment: This question should be merged with the other one since it refers to a different style of connector.

Comment: If you have two separate questions, please post them as separate questions.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/51848/can-i-leave-an-open-port-when-using-push-in-connectors.

Comment: For those wary of the push-in connectors but still want the convenience of push-in, check out lever-nut connectors. I have not seen them in big-box, but we use them all the time for quick test connections at work and they are rock solid. Example: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01GVS7ZES/ref=sxbs_sxwds-stvp_1?pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_p=3171424582&pd_rd_wg=0Q06z&pf_rd_r=N05SGCZWCDGSH8500TNH&pf_rd_s=desktop-sx-bottom-slot&pf_rd_t=301&pd_rd_i=B01GVS7ZES&pd_rd_w=P3wvz&pf_rd_i=lever+nut+conductor&pd_rd_r=E0H9MVP36EH4RTNHCB91&ie=UTF8&qid=1506445220&sr=1

Comment: @statueuphemism yes, yes, yes! Much better! By the way, I'm sorry for VTC earlier, this edit certainly takes care of that... notwithstanding the most recent dup just pointed out.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  If you choose to use push-in type wire connectors, you can insert 1 to *#of_ports* wires into them.

As mentioned in the comments... Some folks don't trust these push-in devices, because of the failings of their back-stab brethren. These devices are listed, and allowed for use by the National Electrical Code. But you have to keep in mind, so were the failed back-stab connectors.  So use at your own risk.