# Is it safe and legal to tape cable with a damaged sheath?

Tags: electrical, wiring

This electrical cable was tightly stapled to an inner stud.  It passes through the wall to an outside light.

While prying the staple off, I tore the outer sheath. Wire doesn't appear damaged.  Light still works.

So: Is it safe to electrical tape this and re-staple to stud?

[image: Torn electrical wire]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to inspect the individual wires inside that outer sheathing.

The black, red, and white insulations should be 100% intact and not nicked/torn in any way or else you run the risk of serious problems.

Whether or not this "fix" is acceptable per code in your area would be determined by the code in your area so when in doubt contact your county/city engineer and they will make sure you do it right.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  Assuming a wire is nicked: how to replace it?  It comes in from a hole in the floor and leaves via a hole in the wall.  I would have to cut out the bad section...and then...do what?

Comment: Could I just splice a new wire in with wire nuts?  Or install a new box and wire it in?

Comment: @Marinaio You should not attempt replace an individual wire. It may be functional but I am sure that any code officer would throw a fit. See https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/32119/is-it-acceptable-or-to-code-to-splice-electrical-wire-outside-of-a-junction-bo and https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/4493/is-there-a-way-to-simply-splice-in-an-additional-length-of-12-2-nm-b-cable. Particularly this answer: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/4501/42053. If you cannot comprehend what those posts are suggesting then hire an electrician.

Comment: Yuch!  Thanks, again.

Comment: @Marinaio You *could* wrap the nicked wire in some tape and then wrap the entire assembly in more tape but once again, I don't know much about whether that is "to code". Even if none of the insulation is torn, you have no way of knowing whether you've introduced stress cracks in the copper when you pried the staple because if you did then that could cause resistance and excessive heating in that section of wire.

Comment: I have a call into an electrician as it's a 60' run from switch to light and the light is too high up for my ladder.  thanks

Comment: @Marinaio I see, good luck and I hope it doesn't cost too much! Sounds like the walls are exposed so I'm sure the electrician will appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

I called an electrician.

They had to snake a wire all the way back to the adjacent room and put a box with a blank on it.