# Can I splice NM-B cable in the ceiling?

Tags: wiring, junction-box, nec, splices

I am moving my bathroom exhaust fan from its current location to 2 feet farther, over the shower cabin.

I need to extend existing wire for this. I can't fish new wire because existing wire has been secured to joist/studs with nail/staples.

As per code I have to splice wire into junction box and it has to be accessible. So I have to install this box in ceilling and hide it with cover plate.

I found [this other post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/4493/is-there-a-way-to-simply-splice-in-an-additional-length-of-12-2-nm-b-cable/4535#4535) which mentions some NEC exception which allows  this product called "Tyco NM splices".

Does this exception apply to my case? NEC language is sometimes hard to interpret.

Comment: Another: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/32119/is-it-acceptable-or-to-code-to-splice-electrical-wire-outside-of-a-junction-bo?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with using this type of splice, but it is still a splice and in using it you have removed the protecting cover of the NM to splice the conductors.

That being said you still need to protect the splice by putting it in a junction box or another approved method.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

The Code language has changed since the quoted link, now (as of 2014 through 2020) saying "...exposed cable wiring and for repair wiring...", removing the word rewiring. Significance of the change would be up to the local Authority Having Jurisdiction, but many agencies such as the [NEW YORK ELECTRICAL INSPECTION AGENCY](https://nyeia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/2011-2014-Code-Changes-Residential-Packet-2.pdf) make it clear this means not for rewiring.

If doing a remodel or renovation you have to demo enough to repair structural, HVAC, plumbing, and electrical up to current codes. No exception is in the NEC for too inconvenient or too expensive.

Comment: Also of value to note that an article by the International Association of Electrical Inspectors  discusses that a 2014 change proposal to include "rewiring" was not accepted. https://iaeimagazine.org/features/enter-the-nonmetallic-sheathed-cable-interconnector/

Answer (score 3):

The fact that the old run is stapled does not mean you can't abandon it and lay a new run right next to it.  The new run would be fished, meaning it does not need to be stapled.