# Can I cut a 240V wire half way?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I put a nail thru a new 240V wire, causing a short and the breaker to jump.

Do I need to replace the complete wire or can I cut out the damaged portion and just install a junction box to isolate the cut?

Fundamentally, what I want to know is does a stove wire need to go uninterrupted straight from oven to breaker box or will it work with a joint in the middle?

I just wanted to save on replacing the complete wire, those are expensive...

Comment: That is very helpful, thank you so very much!

Answer (score 7):

As long as the connections are properly contained within a box, and the box is accessible, there should be no problem doing what you want. However, cables are usually run with very little slack in them, and you'll need enough extra wire to make the connections within the box.  If you can't get enough slack in the line, you'll have to install two junction boxes, or replace a bit of the cable.

Make sure you...

- Use a large enough box.
- Use the proper sized connectors.
- Use the proper sized wire (if needed).
- Make the connections tight enough.

Things to watch out for...

- Aluminum wire.
  Even though a larger size wire has to be used, the price of aluminum wire is often less than copper.
- Electrocution.
  Make sure you turn the breaker off before you begin, and test to make sure the power is actually off.

Comment: I feel like there is another question on the site where someone links to a splice connector that is rated for in-wall use (without a junction box). ring any bells?

Comment: @Steven: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/4493/is-there-a-way-to-simply-splice-in-an-additional-length-of-12-2-nm-b-cable , although I'm not sure there are any in-wall splice kits for wire larger than 12 GA. Since the OP seems to be asking about a stove, I assume it's bigger than that.