# How can I safely extend an existing outlet through an empty space?

Tags: electrical

I have an electrical outlet in the back of a cubby hole over my fireplace as it seemed built for televisions of the CRT variety.

My question is, I plan to just wall off that cubby as to be able to hang a flat screen television on said wall. In doing so, how do I move the electrical outlet forward, from its current position, to the new wall?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't simply run the cord to the receptacle's existing location?

Comment: Because I'm going to place a wall, complete with drywall, between my intended position for an outlet, and its current position.

Comment: What wiring method was used to wire the existing receptacle? Can you move that receptacle + box to the new wall?

Comment: That's basically my question I guess. There's not enough existing wiring to just move it. Could I pigtail a new run off the existing line?

Comment: Is this line run using NM (Romex), some sort of metal-armored cable, or conduit of some flavor?

Comment: Romex, I would assume. But with the proximity of the fireplace (closed, vented box type) it may be shielded. Honestly I'm still in the planning phase.

Comment: We need to know what that run's run with to know what your options are here -- the game changes completely for NM vs metal-armored cables vs conduit.

Comment: When I open up the wall I'll come back and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: In any case, any junction you make must remain accessible.  You can’t seal a junction box up in a sealed cavity.  If there’s not enough wire you may need to locate how that is fed, disconnect the old and then run a new circuit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is enough slack in the existing wire then you should pull it out up to the new outlet box.

If that's not possible then you can leave an access panel through which you can reach the old box and pigtail a short run of wire. Junction boxes must all be accessible using a screwdriver.

If you don't want to leave an access panel you can use correctly rated [inline splices](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/4535/4576).